# How could retrieve all the methods of System.Math

Tags: powershell

I try to retrieve all the methods of [the `[System.Math]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math) as:
[image]

but it just report error:

```
PS C:\Users\me> get-member -name [math]
get-member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:1
```

alternatively tried:

```
PS C:\Users\me> [math].GetMethods() | Select Name, IsStatic -Unique

Name          IsStatic
----          --------
Ceiling           True
Floor             True
Round             True
Truncate          True
IEEERemainder     True
Abs               True
```

How could get a detailed list of all the methods as the above image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-Member -Static` to retrieve static members:

```
[math] |Get-Member -Static
# or
Get-Member -InputObject $([math]) -Static
```